# Loopy Loop through Range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am looping through a range in Excel VBA. I have an IF-Then that checks to see if the a cell contains a number. I then want the address of the cell that contains the number. The problem is my code returns the first cell with a number over and over.

```
For Each Row in Room.Rows
   If IsNumber(Row.Cells(,1)) then
      x = (Row.cells(,1))
   End If
Next Row
```

Comment: what is the `Room`? Is it worksheet or just a range?

Comment: I've noticed in my own work that the `.rows` property of a range acts quite strangely.. like mine today had 200k rows but the `.rows.count` showed 4... i've no idea why. anyways, if you're only after a particular column set the range as that one particular column, then use `.cells`. if you're after multiple columns in a given row range, then again, use `.cells`

Comment: by all that i mean, use `room.cells` as aposed to `room.rows`

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Row in Room.Rows

   If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(range("A" & Row.row)) then

   x = range("A" & Row.row).address
   // do stuff with x

   End If
Next Row
```

Comment: I get a run-time error '1004" Application-define or object-define error

Answer (score 0):

1) don't use variable names that will confuse people (row)

2) in the for each loop example, you don't need to add the .rows ,
   considering your named variable 'row' is a row type.

3) Declare all your variables

4) i changed the code with an other approach :

```
Dim R as Long   
Dim Rg as Range
Dim x as String

For R=1 to Room.rows.count
   set Rg= Room.cells(r,1)
   If IsNumeric(Rg) then
        x = Rg.address
        // do stuff with x
   End If
Next R

set rg= nothing
```

Comment: That did it, I did have to change IsNumeric() to me sub IsNumber(). IsNumeric() was selecting some odd data. Thank All